# How does python lists internally works with different elements types?

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

Basically I want to know how can Python access elements in O(1) time in lists, when those elements are of different types.
Example:

```
my_list = [1,1.54,'hello']

# takes O(1) time
my_list[1]
```

Comment: because they are all references, so Python looks up to where it points to and goes to that place, regardless of what this thing actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of them share one common type: `object`. Python stores an array of objects internally. Details vary with the capability of the language used for the implementation.

Two example implementations:

**CPython**

```
PyObject *
PyList_GetItem(PyObject *op, Py_ssize_t i)
{
    if (!PyList_Check(op)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!valid_index(i, Py_SIZE(op))) {
        _Py_DECLARE_STR(list_err, "list index out of range");
        PyErr_SetObject(PyExc_IndexError, &_Py_STR(list_err));
        return NULL;
    }
    return ((PyListObject *)op) -> ob_item[i];
}
```

Source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L243

**Jython**

```
@Override
public synchronized Object get(int index) {
    return list.get(index).__tojava__(Object.class);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jython/jython/blob/master/src/org/python/core/PyList.java#L1088

Comment: This is not an accurate description of the internals. The fact that all elements share a common Python-level type `object` is completely irrelevant, and the list internals do not store an "array of objects" - a CPython list is backed by an array of pointers.

Comment: In fact, Python objects used to *not* all share a common type, back before type/class unification, but the list internals still worked mostly the same as they do now, with an array of pointers to elements.

Comment: @user2357112 this answer wasn't intended to show the specifics of CPython or any other implementation. It's about the basic idea. The CPython-code is just complementary to show an example. I can also add the Jython-implementation, if that makes it easier for you

Comment: But first, the basic idea is already totally wrong, and second, the question is *about* how the internals work.

Comment: I think that a simple edit of the answer, underlining the importance of the fact that an array of pointers is used would make it sufficiently clear. I really like that the important part of the implementation is cited.

Comment: @user2357112 well, the question didn't even specify an implementation of python. Personally I'd say "all objects are abstracted down to a single type which can be stored in an array" is perfectly fine for such an open question.

Comment: First, I disagree that "all objects are abstracted down to a single type which can be stored in an array" is a "perfectly fine" level of detail, and second, your answer claims that the "single type" involved is Python `object`, which is incredibly misleading. The fact that the objects have a shared Python-level type is irrelevant, and was not always the case. What matters is that the implementation can handle objects of inhomogeneous size through pointers (or Java references or other language-appropriate tools) of equal size.